Ideal hikari leak-detection-threshold time for connection maxLifetime time
I have below datasource config
# 10 minutes
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=600000
# 5 minutes
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=50

My DB queries may take upto max 10 min, how do i configure spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold prop?
It should be equal/greater to maxlifeTime of a connection? why?
FYI -  i have encounterd this error com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection - Apparent connection leak detected, hence i need to figureout ideal time for leak detection
